# Find value from one cell, copy value from cell near to that cell and paste it to another sheet

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I have 2 sheets with different values. I need to find a value from one cell.sheet1 in sheet2 and copy value from nextcell_in_the_same_row.sheet1 to nextcell_in_the_same_row.sheet2.
It is very difficult to explain let look at the example bellow.

E.g.
Before

```
first sheet:
   A  B
1 aaa 123    
2 bbb 456
3 ccc 789
4 ddd 122
second sheet:
   A  B
1 aaa
2 ada 
3 cca 
4 ccc
```

After

```
first sheet:
   A  B
1 aaa 123    
2 bbb 456
3 ccc 789
4 ddd 122
second sheet:
   A  B
1 aaa *need to find value in the first sheet and copy value from B2 because aaa in A1*
2 ada *value does not exist in the first sheet so copy nothing*
3 cca *not need to copy because no value in the first sheet*
4 ccc *need to copy the value from B3*
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Been a while, but check out VLOOKUP and use it in the formula on the second sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `VLOOKUP` along with an `IFERROR`.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0), "")
```

This will do what you described (well described, by the way!) in your question. Drag the formula down in `Sheet2` till the bottom.

`VLOOKUP` takes the value of `A1` in sheet 2 (no sheet reference because the value is in the same sheet as the formula) and looks it up in column A of `Sheet1`.

It returns the second value (hence why `2`) of the table selected in the formula (column A is 1, column B is 2).

The 0 tells the `VLOOKUP` to look for exact matches. You don't need approximate match here.

And `IFFERROR` is there in case `VLOOKUP` doesn't find anything (like with `ada`) and instead of giving `#N/A`, returns an empty cell, `""`.