# Get result for one column if data associated with that column is equal to two other columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have data like this in Excel:

```
ColA         ColB        ColC           ColD
1B                         1B            E 
2B                         4B            C
3B                         5B            E
4B
5B
```

I would appreciate a formula to be applied in ColB  for the following result:

```
ColA         ColB        ColC           ColD
1B            E            1B            E 
2B                         4B            C
3B                         5B            E
4B            C
5B            E
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two columns, and returning a specific adjacent cell in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191835/comparing-two-columns-and-returning-a-specific-adjacent-cell-in-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be much simpler than the possible duplicate suggested - ie just a very standard LOOKUP (which is duplicated elsewhere even MORE often!):

in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,0),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

in cell B2, enter

=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$4,0)),"")

and paste down

Should do the trick!

Comment: assuming the row with 1B is the row 2